# PHP File upload redirect

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

Ok, this is might sound like a security hole but let's ignore that for a while. I need to allow users to upload a file to my website but I want to be in control of generating that file. I have a form where I want the user to create the new file and then that file should be the one that is uploaded. Is there anyway I can subvert the file upload control so that instead of popping up the 'Open' dialog box, it pops up my form and then when the form is submitted, the new created file is the one that's uploaded with the control?

Alternatively, I figure I could just use a regular button and a bit of JavaScript to open up my form in a window but then I would need a way to automatically the file to the form to be uploaded when my external form closes.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be in control of generating that file, why not just have the form submit all of the information required to generate the control, and then generate the file on the server?

Comment: My form is more of an interactive process with the user. It can't be done behind the scenes after submitting. It is also being incorporated into some of our legacy software that's pretty set in how it's designed. Trust me, I know this is not an ideal situation unfortunately it's also one of those situations that can't be avoided.

Comment: Then without some kind of browser plugin that can write files arbitrarily, this simply cannot be done.  The browser will not let you just write new files to the user's disk, even if you are going to delete them.  You might consider writing a Java applet to do this.  (Flash will not work, since its data storage is sandboxed.)